# Did the USSR have any position on global warming?

Tags: soviet-union, climate

I assume they rejected it, given the anti-malthusian nature of Marxism.

Comment: In 1989 climate scientists were still sounding the alarm on anthropomorphic ***global cooling***; I kid you not. It wasn't until after the ozone--hole crisis had been averted around 2000 that global warming hit the radar with any force.

Comment: AGW has been around in some form since the 1800s. There must have been some point when soviet journals talked about it.

Comment: Okay - you are less than 30 years old and have no memory of the "Oh no! Another ice age is coming and sea level is going to drop 300 feet." alarms of the late 20th Century. There was absolutely no talk of an impending global warming crisis at that time (pre 2000 or so) because all climate scientists were concerned only with stopping global cooling. At some point, during the (successfully handled) ozone layer crisis, the refrain switched.

Comment: There was much talk of it before 1940. AGW comes and goes.

Comment: Global warming was not on the agenda while Soviet Union existed.

Comment: Tyler already refuted that. Stop downvoting.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It's widely claimed that the scientific consensus in the 70s expected global cooling, but on examination it's not the case. There were some such predictions, and the popular press took the idea of cooling and ran with it, but the majority of contemporary researchers were substantially more focused on warming. This 2008 survey made an attempt at teasing the two apart - http://dx.doi.org/10.1175/2008BAMS2370.1 - and is worth a read.

Comment: Incidentally, skimming the list of "expected warming" papers there (table 1) flags up three by [Mikhail Budyko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Budyko), a fairly prominent Soviet scientist in the 70s who published predictions of warming. This is of course not the same as "the USSR" having a position on it, but it clearly wasn't a politically forbidden topic - he was able to publish this in both American and Soviet journals, and appointed to senior academic positions.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" I'd think it's probably the first reason where the downvotes come from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On paper the USSR had some of the strictest environmental laws in the world, however, in most cases they were just paper laws and were widely ignored. Ironically, the USSR did very detailed studies on environment contaminants such as mercury. In some cases the EPA actually used Soviet reports on mercury and other toxic chemicals as a data source because the Soviet studies were so detailed.

In general, the Soviet Union had a lackluster record on the environment. One typical example of this was the sulfur dioxide problem. Behind the iron curtain making monumental statues of Lenin, Stalin, etc, out of cheap materials was popular, so in many cases these statues were heavily affected by acid rain. The Soviet response was to hide the affected statues.

In 1988, the United States, USSR and Japan all voted against a UN proposal to hold carbon dioxide emissions at 1988 levels through the year 2000.

In 1989, at the [Malta Summit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malta_Summit), Bush brought up the upcoming formation of the IPCC and associated conference on "climate change" with Gorbachev. Environmental advocates hailed this as "progress". Generally speaking, the global warming initiative did not catch on until the 1990s when the Soviet Union had already collapsed.

Years later, Gorbachev became, like Gore, a strong proponent of global warming activism. However, there was no significant interest in the global warming topic during his tenure as the President of the Soviet Union.

Comment: Somebody downvoted you for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: Except he was never a premier.

Comment: @Anixx I forgot that they changed the head of state to "President" in the 1960s. I modified my answer to correct that.

Comment: President of the USSR title was introduced 15th March 1990 by Gorbachev for himself and existed a little more than a year. Not in 1960s of course. The premier ministers in the 1980s-1990s were Tikhonov (1980-1985), Ryzhkov (1985-1991), Pavlov (1991).

Comment: @Anixx Sorry, keeping track of the exact titles of Soviet dictators is not high on my list of priorities. Can we just call them "Grand Poobahs"?

Comment: Gorbachev became head of state (Chairman of the Presidium of the Supreme Council) October 1, 1988. Immediately he started to rename the titles and inventing positions, for instance he renamed the title to Chairman of the Supreme Council in May 25, 1989. And in 1990 made himself President of the USSR (amendment to constitution introducing new title).